# How to put all the rows in a HashMap in while loop iteration

Tags: java

Issue : There will 3 records in testcaseInputs  . All the three records are iterated, but at end the "rows" map has only one record which is iterated in the last.  I want rows map should contain all the three records.

Issue 2: The iteration takes record1, then record 2, record 3 .. again it takes record 1 or 3 for iteration. I don't know why.

```
public void addinputtosc() {
try {
    Map<String, List<JsonNode>> testrecords = null;
    Map<String, String> rows = new Hashmap<String, String>();

    // this function takes the input sheet , sheet name and returns data in Map<String, List<JsonNode>> format.
    testrecords = fetchScenariosData("C:\\testData.xlsx", "input", "inputParam");
    Iterator<Map.Enry<String, List<JsonNode>>> entries = testRecords.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, List<JsonNode>> entry = entries.next();
        String scenarioName = entry.getKey();
        List<JsonNode> testcaseInputs = entry.getValue();
        if (scenarioName.equalsIgnoreCase("TestCase1")) {
            ListIterator<JsonNode> listIterator = testCaseInputs.listIterator();
            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                for (JsonNode tcinputs :testCaseInputs) {
                    String keyValue = tcinputs.toString();
                    String newKeyValue = keyValue.replaceAll("[{}]", "");
                    String[] keyValue1 = newKeyValue.split(",");
                    for (String j : keyValue1) {
                        String[] keyValueorg = j.split(":");
                        row.put(keyValueorg[0].substring(1, keyValueorg[0].length() - 1), keyValueorg[1].substring(1, keyValueorg[1].length() - 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: The characters `[` and `]` and `{` and `}` are special characters in a java regular expression. If you want the literal characters, escape them by preceding each one with a double backslash, i.e. "\\\[\\{\\}\\\]"

Comment: `if (scenarioName.equalsIgnoreCase("TestCase1"))` it seems you look just at testcase1

Comment: @Tigan Lon,Yes, for TestCase1 , there are 3 records.

Comment: try debugging it (debug mode or just sysout stuff to console - keyValue, newKeyValue and so on), and look at what you are putting in the rows map, most probably your key is not created right and you overwrite the previous values in each iteration

Comment: @Abra, ya will tune it. Thanks . could you please help in the actual issue.

Comment: The debugging will help you with the actual issue. For one of us to debug it would require you to have put an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example) into your question.

Comment: @NomadMaker I think if the OP wanted someone to debug his code for him, he would have to [edit] his question and not only post a [mcve] but also a sample `testrecords` map.

Comment: @Abra I read his reply to you that he would rather somebody tell him the answer, rather than help him with debugging. So yes, I believe that he doesn't really want to do the work himself. I do try to believe the best of everybody, but his response "could you please help in the actual issue" causes me to doubt this.

Comment: @Abra,NomadMaker, please dont be under impression that i dint dbug:). This internally calls other mthds. I am beginr and trying to get some expertise hlp to reduce the time which i m speding exploring and dbugging again. I am getting the output exaclty the way i need, but the code retrieves only 1 rcrd, actually it should write 3 rcrds to "rows" hmap. I'sure I mst be missing some stmt,some brk or cndition, or i might be taking a long aproach,thti am trying since this  afternoon. I could have shown the actual i/p sheet but restrctd(VPN).. tx .. :)

Comment: {Validate File =
[{"File Source Env.":"Unix","TC_ID":"tc1","File Path":"/tmp/test.dat","Date":"20190101"},
{"File Source Env.":"Unix-qa","TC_ID":"tc2","File Path":"/tmp/test1.dat","Date":"20190201"},
{"File Source Env.":"Unix-dev","TC_ID":"tc3","File Path":"/tmp/test2.dat","Date":"20190201"}]}

Comment: testrecords looks like this. I m splitting Validate file  to key and remaining to Value of type List<JsonNode>. In while loop im iterating JsonNode list , did some replace and split and again I tried to put that in to rows<strng, sring> hashmap. Ideally rows hashmap should have 12 inserts, but its showing only first record in the Json file in rows map.BUt it iterates all the records in while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue : There will 3 records in testcaseInputs . All the three records
>   are iterated, but at end the "rows" map has only one record which is
>   iterated in the last. I want rows map should contain all the three
>   records.

This is happening because of this line :

```
rows.put(keyValueorg[0].substring(1, keyValueorg[0].length() - 1), keyValueorg[1].substring(1, keyValueorg[1].length() - 1));
```

when you are procesing frist JsonNode suppose this as per your example

`{"File Source Env.":"Unix","TC_ID":"tc1","File Path":"/tmp/test.dat","Date":"20190101"}`

the HashMap `rows` will contain content as :

{Date=20190101, path=/tmp/test.dat, TC_ID=tc1, File Source Env.=Unix}

now when again this codeis executed for second JsonNode suppose this :

`{"File Source Env.":"Unix-qa","TC_ID":"tc2","File Path":"/tmp/test1.dat","Date":"20190201"}`

as per your code , keys which will be calculated for this new record `(keyValueorg[0].substring(1, keyValueorg[0].length() - 1))` is same as the previous key values that are stored in hashmap i.e. Date, File Source Env, TC_ID, Path by the first record. 
Since these key values are already present in hashmap there values get updated by new values which is property of PUT operation of HashMap(if key is there then it just override with new values else insert new key in map).

This process will continue and hence only last record values are seen in hashmap.

In order to keep all key-value pairs of all records in single hashmap you need to create different key for each record.  Otherwise create a nested hashmap.

Comment: Glad to know it was helpful